# cannot implicit convert type string string[]

Tags: c#

I want to store string into string array, but it shows error.
Here is my code:

```
List <ResponseObject> myresponse =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseObject>>(responseFromServer);
string [] DomainArray;
for (int i = 0; i < myresponse.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes.Count; j++)
    {
        DomainArray = myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to initiatialize the array, like this: `string [] DomainArray = new string[myresponse.Count];`

Comment: that is a declaration of the variable

Comment: @HugoQuintelaRibeiro: this won't work because it's the count of myresponses AND EmailAddressSuffixes

Comment: since arrays are not dynamic, think about working with lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes in my above code. first from @Hugo and second from @Roma

```
List <ResponseObject> myresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseObject>>(responseFromServer);
List<string> DomainArray = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myresponse.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes.Count; j++)
    {
        DomainArray.Add(myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will receive a ArgumentOutOfRangeException as you are setting the array to a length of myresponse rather than the length of all the EmailAddressSuffixes

Comment: @AhmedJalal: have a look at my answer used List<string> instead of static arrays

Comment: It will only work if each each response item has only one EmailAddressSuffix

Comment: after checking again @bolt19 answer is according to  my expectations

Comment: @AhmedJalal thank you for unaccepting my answer, copy paste it to your edited answer and mark this as answer and accept it to earn reputation for your own.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign the DomainArray (which is an array of strings) to a single string.

Try this, it adds all the values to a list then converts to list to an array:

```
    List<ResponseObject> myresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseObject>>(responseFromServer);
    List<string> DomainList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myresponse.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes.Count; j++)
        {
            DomainList.Add(myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes[j]);
        }
    }
    var DomainArray = DomainList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List <ResponseObject> myresponse =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseObject>>(responseFromServer);
var DomainArray = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myresponse.Count; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes.Count; j++)
{
DomainArray.Add( myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes[j] );
}
}
```

Then you can get the array (if required) using `DomainArray.ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are not dynamic, think about working with lists:

```
List <ResponseObject> myresponse =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseObject>>(responseFromServer);
List<string> DomainArray = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myresponse.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes.Count; j++)
    {
        DomainArray.add(myresponse[i].EmailAddressSuffixes[j]);
    }
}
```